# Prevent .bat file closing when I run Go script via drop down

Tags: batch-file, go, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, gosublime

I have this little Hello World program written in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

I use Sublime Text 3 with GoSublime. Something misconfigured, because Tools -> Build command not working, just only when I type in the console:

```
go build
```

Then the editor creating the .exe program.

So I want to use a basic .bat file, where I drag and drop my hello.go program:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
start "" "C:\Go\bin\go.exe" "run" "%~f1" pause
```

It runs without problem, but unfortunately closes when it's finished.

Can You help to solve this? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just that `start` launches it in it's own process?

so:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
C:\Go\bin\go.exe run %~f1 
pause
```

Should work?